# My jQuery ,jQuerymobile code doesn't work on PC, but perfectly on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I was working on a code using jQuery, jQuerymobile, and soundcloud API. The code works perfectly on server and on jsfiddle.net but when I run it locally it does not work. I've tried it with a local copy of jQuery library but it still does not work on a PC.
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: This question needs more information. Can you post a link to the jsfiddle sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you loading the JavaScript files? Maybe you have script tags with a protocol-relative URL, such as:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If this is the case, things aren't working locally because it's looking in a local file system protocol instead of HTTP. You can just change this to use the absolute form of the URL:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```